# Derivate of composition of vector functions

Tags: vector-analysis

I have troubles to find derivate of composition of two vector functions:$f(x,y)=(x^2,y^2), g(a,b)=(a\cos b,a\sin b)$ where $a>0, b\in(0,2\pi)$. So i need to find $d(f o g)$.
I am not even sure what formula to use, so any link on already done examples or explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$(f \circ g)(a,b)= (a^2 \cos^2 b, a^2 \sin^2 b).$$

Now compute the Jacobian matrix of $f \circ g.$

Comment: In the first row of matrix we first have derivate of $a^2\cos^2 b$ with respect to $a$ first, and then to b. And in the second row we have derivate of $a^2\sin^2 b$ first with respect to a, and then to b. Is this correct, and should I know calculate the determinant of the resulting matrix?